# Calculate Nearest Location to Coordinates

Tags: python, openstreetmap

Let's say I had a list of locations (the coordinates) and one location (again, coordinates), can I sort the list of locations depending on how close they are to the location?

I'm wondering if this is possible with Python and OpenStreetMap.

Comment: You don't need OpenStreetMap, just loop through the list and perform the mathematical formula to calculate distance against the single point. Then just sort by the distance values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's say each location is a point with lat and long like `(2, 3)`. So your list would be:

```
x = [(1, 2), (5, 6), (7, -3)]
```

Your location would be:

```
y = (4, 5)
```

Then your job is to calculate the distance between locations from the list `x` to your location `y`:

```
import math
def distance(a, b):
    return math.hypot(a[1] - b[1], a[0] - b[0])

distances = []
for i in x:
    distances.append((i, distance(i, y)))
# sort coordinate by distance
distances = sorted(distances, key=lambda i: x[1])
```